# Eclipse AST Parser is removing my rules

Tags: java, eclipse

I have added a new rule in `"java.g"` grammar file, but while parsing my java file, `Eclipse AST parser` is removing my rule.

Is there any specific changes need to be done on `Parser` or `grammar` level to retain my rule so that `AST` can visit my rules ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that the way the rules have been configured in java.g grammar file,

If the non-terminal cannot be used for generating terminal string, then it will not be considered in while parsing.

This is one of the reason. When I used my rule to generate a terminal string, at least it is reducing my rule.